# How to discover Bluetooth pairing mechanism on remote device in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth, iot

I don't want to actually connect to those device. I just want to discover or deduce somehow pairing mechanism. Is it Legacy (PIN), SSP (Numeric Comparison, Just Works, NI/NO, Passkey) or OOB Pairing (NFC, RFID).